# GLSL это отдельный от C++ язык программирования?

Tags: c++, opengl

GLSL это отдельный от C++ язык программирования? он сильно отличается от C++? Или там все связано с C++?

Comment: Вообще никакой связи с си++.

Comment: Ну как бы это из биологии... Когда эволюция приводит к одинаковой форме совершенно разные виды, типа, дельфины похожи на акул :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GLSL - это c-подобный язык, т.е. синтаксис более-менее похож на язык c/c++, но по сравнению с этими языками высокого уровня обладает своим набором инструкций/команд, функций

с c++ его объединяет именно схожесть в структуре кода, если так сказать можно

GLSL отчасти ограничен задачами для которых он и создавался - создание шейдеров с учётом архитектуры видео-карт, универсальным языком его никогда делать не собирались и отсюда все его огромные ограничения по сравнению с c/c++

зная c/c++ и принципы работы с графикой вы можете понимать, что делает код на GLSL (так же как и на HLSL для Direct3D), но опять же - код общего назначения не будет работать, если вы его попытаетесь откомпилировать на GLSL (хотя слово компиляция тут не совсем подходит)